# What's the best way to get address difference between a class variable and the starting address of a class object?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-address, unique-key, datamember

Need to generate unique keys for the class data members. Hence I am thinking of getting the difference between the address of the variable minus the address of the class object. For example:

```
struct X {
  int i;  // &i - &X() = 0  (GCC)
  double d;  // &d - &X() = 8  (GCC)
};
```

This is a one time exercise and hence will be happening in very beginning of the code execution for all the interested classes. So typically I will be declaring a dummy object of the class and finding the address difference by typecasting. Such as:

```
X x;
keyOf_i = long(&x.i) - long(&x);
keyOf_d = long(&x.d) - long(&x);
```

Is there any better way?
Assume that the access specifier (`private`) are not the problem.

Will be also interested, if someone has got any other approach to generate unique keys for class data variables apart from this way.

---

**Update**: With using `offseof()` macro, I am getting following warning in G++-6:

> offsetof within non-standard-layout type ‘MyClass’ is undefined

Actually I have some string & other class variables as well inside `MyClass`. I am fine, even if this undefined thing gives unique address whatsoever. However, would like to get more information of `offsetof()` and other alternatives.

Comment: @iammilind I can't think about difference answer, `offsetof` is undefined behavior for non standard layout

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Danh can you elaborate more on the "standard layout types". In what kind of situations this difference can fail? I thought that, the difference between the address of the class object and the address of its data member, always remain constant. When will this difference become undefined? BTW, I am not interested in the accurate difference as such. Rather, I am just interested in unique difference for all the variables of the class. Please suggest.

Comment: Google for "pointer-to-member". A pointer-to-member is a thing that lets you access some member of a struct or class instance if you are given a pointer to the instance as well.

Comment: You might want to use uintptr_t to make sure the pointers fit in the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using offsetof() macro for this. Check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html for more details.

Sample code below from the man page:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct s {
        int i;
        char c;
        double d;
        char a[];
    };

    /* Output is compiler dependent */

    printf("offsets: i=%ld; c=%ld; d=%ld a=%ld\n",
            (long) offsetof(struct s, i),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, c),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, d),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, a));
    printf("sizeof(struct s)=%ld\n", (long) sizeof(struct s));

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```